# Change value with button on another page

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

I'm doing a calendar with html/css/js. 
I have an index.html with this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>App calendario</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="myfunc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form> 
<button class="button-customize" onclick="MyFunction(4)" type="button">4 - 10</button> 
</form>
</body>
```

The js is:

```
function MyFunction(x) {
window.open("settimana.html","_self");
document.getElementById("Giorno_1").innerHTML = x;}
```

and another page, settimana.html, is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Settimana</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="myfunc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#"> 
 <button class="button-customize" type="submit" id="Giorno_1" name="Giorno_1">Giorno 1</button> 
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

the problem is that the value of button in page settimana.html doesn't change. Why? Help me please.

Comment: settimana and index both use the same script file, but that doesn't mean they share the same one. They both have a copy in memory, so changes in one will not affect the other. You need to pass any data you need before its loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You need to say your script where it should send its data to the server. so you need something like

```
<from method="POST" action="target.php">......</form>
```

iMo you need to have a server script which consumes your formular data via "$_POST" globals (in PHP). I guess with pure html, you can just send an email with the form data.

http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.post.php